# White space between images in email newsletter in Gmail app on Android-device

Tags: html, css, email, html-email, newsletter

I am creating an email template having the following html:

```
<tr>
    <td valign='top' align='center' style='font-size:0;white-space: nowrap;'>
        <img src='' align='top' border='0' style='display:block;width:620px;border:0px;white-space: nowrap;'/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align='center' style='font-size:0;white-space: nowrap;'>
        <a href='#' style='font-size:0;display:block; border:0px;line-height:0;white-space: nowrap;' target='_blank'>
            <img align='top' border='0' src='#' style='display:block;border:0pxwidth:620px;white-space: nowrap;'/>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
</tr>
```

I am getting white space only on **gmail app on Android**. 
Any idea where I am missing anything?

Comment: Did you seriously copy the title from the URL slug from [this forum thread](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?301839-White-space-in-e-mail-newsletter-ONLY-when-seen-through-Gmail-app-on-Android-device)? I guess it beats trying and failing to come up with a proper question title yourself...

Comment: Could we see the code for the whole table? Maybe some info on the image dimensions that are being input

Comment: Please remove the duplicated `</tr>` at the end of your html

Answer (score 1):

In addition to zero'ing out the font size via `font-size: 0;`, **zero out the line height via `line-height: 0;`**:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="">
    <tr>
        <td valign='top' align='center' style='font-size:0; line-height: 0;'>
            <img src='#' align='top' width='620' border='0' style='display:block;'/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign='top' align='center' style='font-size:0; line-height: 0;'>
            <a href='#' target='_blank'>
                <img src='#' align='top' width='620' border='0' style='display:block;'/>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**NOTE:** If `line-height: 0;` causes images to totally collapse, try `line-height: 1;`.

---

I've also cleaned up the extra `<tr>` at the end and removed a bunch of CSS rules that don't impact spacing.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail's DOCTYPE can create extra space under images.
Here are a few workarounds [as mentioned in emailonacid website](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/12_things_you_must_know_when_developing_for_gmail_and_gmail_mobile_apps#gmail_tip12) (these work in Hotmail and Yahoo! Beta as well):

1.) Add style display:block to the image element

```
<img src=“test.jpg” style=“display:block”>
```

2.) Add align absbottom in the image element

```
<img src=“test.jpg” align=“absbottom”>
```

3.) Add align texttop to the image element

```
<img src=“test.jpg” align=” texttop ”>
```

4.) Add line-height 10px or lower in the containing TD

```
<td style=“line-height:10px”>
```

5.) Add font-size 6px or lower in the containing TD

```
<td style=“font-size:6px”>
```